# Deserializing detail of SOAP message

Tags: c#, soap, xml-serialization, windows-8, .net-4.5

I am working on a Windows Store application.

I have the following manually created Fault class:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", ElementName = "Fault")]
public partial class SoapFault
{
    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, ElementName = "faultcode")]
    public String FaultCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, ElementName = "faultstring")]
    public String FaultDescription { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, ElementName = "detail")]
    public InnerException[] Detail { get; set; }
}

    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://my.namespace.com", TypeName = "InnerException")]
    public partial class InnerException 
    {
        [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, ElementName = "message")]
        public String Message { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the reply of the server i am trying to read:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><env:Fault><faultcode>env:Server</faultcode><faultstring>internal error</faultstring><detail><ns2:InnerException xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ns1.my.namespace.com" xmlns:ns2="http://my.namespace.com" xmlns:ns3="http://ns3.my.namespace.com"><message>internal error</message></ns2:InnerException ></detail></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

The way i am trying to read it is as follows:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
{
    string SoapNamespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    try
    {
         var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SoapFault));

         reader.ReadStartElement("Envelope", SoapNamespace);
         reader.ReadStartElement("Body", SoapNamespace);

         var fault = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as SoapFault;

         reader.ReadEndElement();
         reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         throw new Exception("Exception was thrown:" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I have tried adding namespaces, changing the XmlElement Attributes, but i always end up with the Detail property in the SoapFault being NULL. When i change the type to object, i at least get a XmlNode set which contains the data.

What must i change in this code to get the correct class instantiated on serialization?

Please note: I am unfortunatly forced to create the calls by hand and cannot use auto-generated code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heavily inspired by [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document), I think this should do the trick.

I generated the class as follows:

1. Save the Xml server reply to disk (c:\temp\reply.xml)
2. xsd c:\temp\reply.xml /o:"c:\temp"
3. xsd c:\temp\reply.xsd reply_app1.xsd /classes /o:"c:\temp"
4. Add reply_app1.cs to your project.

This resulted in:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.269
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.1.
// 

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Envelope {

    private EnvelopeBody[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Body")]
    public EnvelopeBody[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public partial class EnvelopeBody {

    private EnvelopeBodyFault[] faultField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Fault")]
    public EnvelopeBodyFault[] Fault {
        get {
            return this.faultField;
        }
        set {
            this.faultField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public partial class EnvelopeBodyFault {

    private string faultcodeField;

    private string faultstringField;

    private EnvelopeBodyFaultDetail detailField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string faultcode {
        get {
            return this.faultcodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.faultcodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string faultstring {
        get {
            return this.faultstringField;
        }
        set {
            this.faultstringField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public EnvelopeBodyFaultDetail detail {
        get {
            return this.detailField;
        }
        set {
            this.detailField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public partial class EnvelopeBodyFaultDetail {

    private InnerException innerExceptionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://my.namespace.com")]
    public InnerException InnerException {
        get {
            return this.innerExceptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.innerExceptionField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://my.namespace.com")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://my.namespace.com", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class InnerException {

    private string messageField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string message {
        get {
            return this.messageField;
        }
        set {
            this.messageField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, it is auto generated, but I figured that would be the easiest way to create a class that you would be able to deserialize. Which you can do like this:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Data/reply.xml"));

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(document.OuterXml));
```

Which correctly picked up the `Detail` property. In your case you would need to use the `XmlReader` like you were doing before instead of my `new StringReader(document.OuterXml)`, and wrap it in a using block, etc.

Keep in mind that some of the property names of the deserialized object won't match up exactly with what you had in your `SoapFault` class (it's now called `Envelope`, for example), and some of the properties are expressed as arrays rather than single objects, but you could probably tweak the Xsd to suit if need be.

Comment: for step #3 above, if step #2 generated more than 2 files, you might need to list them all as arguments to xsd, ie. **xsd** *reply.xsd* *reply_app1.xsd* *reply_app2.xsd* ... etc

Comment: You are a life-saver